# Java monitor memory usage of unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, memory, garbage-collection

I am trying to store the memory each unit test uses into in a database. So i calculate the free memory before and after the tests with:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()
```

If there are garbage collections during the test i count them via:

```
//returns garbage collection count
private long calculateGarbageCollectionCount(){
    List<GarbageCollectorMXBean> garbageCollectorMXBean = ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans();
    return garbageCollectorMXBean.get(garbageCollectorMXBean.size()-1).getCollectionCount();
}
```

Now i need an idea how much memory on average the garbage collections sets free to do something like this:

```
gcCount*memoryReleased+freeMemoryAtStart-freeMemoryAtEnd
```

Is there at least a rough estimation how much memory gets release during a garbage collection? I tried using MemoryPoolMXBean with the getPeak method but the value i get is confusing me. Its bigger than the total Memory the JVM has.

Comment: "Got some trouble with garbage collector errors in unit tests" - care to share what kind of errors ?

Comment: There are tools for that, e.g. profilers. Don't try to invent home grown solutions.

Comment: @alfasin these two:    
    "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" and
    "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

Comment: I had to edit my question, it was to broad. Maybe you can take a look at it again.

Comment: `freeMemory()` reports the directly available (already allocated) memory or in other words, the free portion of `totalMemory()`, but `totalMemory()` is not a constant. So `freeMemory()` may report more memory, because more memory had been allocated rather than freed by the GC. It might be even the other way round, `freeMemory()` reporting less memory, because the GC has freed so much that the JVM gave some memory back to the operating system. So it’s not the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a useful class that helped:
https://github.com/Netflix/spectator/blob/master/spectator-ext-gc/src/main/java/com/netflix/spectator/gc/GcLogger.java

With this class it is possible to catch garbage collection events and more so gather information what happened in them.

As a rough estimation how much memory a unit tests uses i trigger a garbage collection before the start. Calculate the free memory before and after the test and sum up how much memory got released during garbage collections.

Comment: Good start for a self-answer. Although you always want to put some real content of that link you give - links can break. And welcome to "upvote" levels ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to create your own "profiling application". You should rather choose between:

1. learning how to "debug" the garbage collector - by understanding the **logs** the GC can be creating for you. See [here](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/how-to-monitor-java-garbage-collection) for example.
2. if that "doesn't do" - look into *existing* tools to help with that. Like [visualvm](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/intro.html) (part of the Oracle JDK) - or even commerical tools such as [your kit](https://www.yourkit.com/).

In other words: don't invent your own thing here. Rely on existing, working, robust technology instead.